# How can we plot an equation in 3 variables on a 2D plane in context with functions of pair of Random Variables?

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, random-variables, graphing-functions

I came across the following question:

[The Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahIHt.png)

I tried solving it, the following is my attempt:

$$
P[W\le w] =  P[XY\le w] = P[Y\le w/X]
$$

And then I simply double integrated keeping the limits of X on the outer integral and between 0 and 1, and that of Y between 0 and $w/x$. But the answer is wrong 'cause finally  I ended up calculating $$[w*ln(x)]$$ between 0 and 1.

[The solution as given in Probability and Stochastic Processes-Roy D. Yates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKmwA.png)

1. Why is my answer wrong?
2. What I'm not able to understand is that the plot given should be a 3D plot, how can it be represented in a 2D plane?

Answer (score 1):

(1) $\mathsf{P}(Y\le w/X)=\int_0^1\int_0^{1\wedge w/x}1\,dy\,dx=w(1-\ln w)$ for $w\in [0,1]$.

(2) It is a [level curve](https://mathinsight.org/level_sets) of the function $f(x,y)=xy$.

Comment: A few doubts: What's the upper limit of the inner integral? The level curve doesn't matched with the solution figure. Also please answer the doubts marked as 1. and 2.

Comment: $a\wedge b = \min(a,b)$; What curve are you talking about?

Comment: What does 1^w/x means(The upper limit of inner integral)? I mean this curve:https://mathinsight.org/level_sets, the one you've attached

Comment: 1. See the previous comment. 2. The link gives examples of level curves/sets (you asked how a 3d function can be represented in a 2D plot).